# How to solve this cubic Integral?

Tags: integration, discrete-time

I tried to solve this integral but I have problem with the cubic term because I can't add $\sin(\frac{n{\pi}x}{L})$:

$$\int_{0}^1 \Biggl[ A\Biggl(\sum_{n=1}^N q_n(t)\sin(\frac{n{\pi}x}{L})\Biggr)^3\sin(\frac{m{\pi}x}{L})\Biggr]dx $$

where $n = 1$ to $30$;
      $m = 1$ to $30$;
      $A$ is a constant.

Comment: It seems to be related with Fourier Series and I wonder if integration interval is $[0,1]$ or $[0,L]$.

Comment: Is m being summed over here too? What do you mean by $m$ = 1 to 30?

Comment: for $\m=1 to 30$ that means $\m$ can have different values.

Comment: And for interval if assume that L=1 we can put [0,1]  or [0,L] never mind